# iPhone 6 plus dimensions showing up as 375.0 x 667.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-size

This one is perplexing me.

```
println("screenWidth \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)")
println("screenHeight \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)")
println("viewWidth \(self.view.bounds.size.width)")
println("viewHeight \(self.view.bounds.size.height)")
```

iphone 6 plus **(USING SIMULATOR)** returns the correct size for an 6 plus:

```
deviceWidth 414.0
deviceHeight 736.0
viewWidth 414.0
viewHeight 736.0
```

iphone 6 plus **(REAL DEAL)** returns the correct size for a regular ole 6:

```
deviceWidth 375.0
deviceHeight 667.0
viewWidth 375.0
viewHeight 667.0
```

How might this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device has the Display Zoom set to *Zoomed* under Settings->Display & Brightness.

Quoting a post from the Apple Developer Forum:

> If the phone is set for zoomed mode, you get either the iPhone 5S screen size (on iPhone 6) or the iPhone 6 size (on iPhone 6 Plus). Keep in mind that on iPhone 6 Plus in zoomed mode you still get a 3x screen, and thus your 3x assets are used.

Comment: You the man Tomas! Thanks for the explaination, this had me pretty confused